# how to insert variables into mysql query

Tags: python

hello i am new to python, i started learning how to work with mysql but the question arose - how to insert variables into mysql query?

I have code like this now:

```py
table_name = "bot"
variable = 15

mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO %s (Id) 
                        VALUES
                        (%s) """
```

I try to execute the code, but it gives an error: SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
attempt to call a nil value

How to write the code correctly? thanks

Comment: Your mysql insert query should be a regular python string (in single or double quotes). Triple-double quotes are for block comments in python. You can use fstrings to insert your variables (not sure if you need single quotes or ` within your query). Put your python variable names in curly braces like this. mysql_insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_varname}" (and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example taken from [here](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/).

```
...
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO Employee
                   (id, Name, Joining_date, salary) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"""

insert_tuple_1 = (1, "Json", "2019-03-23", 9000)
cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, insert_tuple_1)
...
```

In your case:

```
   cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO bot VALUES (%s)""", (15,))
```

Comment: it helped me <3

Answer (score -1):

Just use :`mySql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO" +table_name+"VALUES " + variable`

Comment: thanks, but now i got an error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Comment: First of all, you should not just use String interpolation for SQL-Queries. That makes your Query vulnerable for SQL injections. Like mentioned in the next Solution by balderman.