# Why am I receiving MariaDB syntax error when appending BETWEEN AND at the end of my INSERT INTO statement?

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I seem to get a SQL syntax error after I add in the python code for the BETWEEN AND SQL query.

Code in question:

```
sqlInsertQuery = """
INSERT INTO `table` (`row1`, `row2`, `row3`, `row4`, `row5`, `row6`, `row7`, `date_modified`, `row9`)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `row2` = %s, `row3` = %s, `row4` = %s, `row5` = %s, `row6` = %s, `row7` = %s, `date_modified` = %s, `row9` = %s
WHERE `date_modified` BETWEEN %s AND %s 
"""

between1 = "07/18/2021 00:00:00"
between2 = "08/03/2021 00:00:00"

sqlInsertData = (row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, `date_modified`, row9, between1, between2)

# Link to the method I used for this statement
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65225153/how-to-insert-variables-into-mysql-query

databaseConnectionCursor.execute(sqlInsertQuery, sqlInsertData)
```

Error in question:

> mariadb.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `WHERE` row8 `BETWEEN ? AND ?` at line 1

Is there something wrong with how I'm utilizing %s for my BETWEEN AND statement? The INSERT INTO statement worked fine until after I appended the BETWEEN AND statement. All the rows are formatted as VARCHAR for my table and the variables are declared as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a WHERE clause in an INSERT statement; that's why that's a syntax error. Such a thing is simply [not in the spec](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/) for MySQL/MariaDB INSERT statements.